# How to split text based on numbers with dots in Python?

Tags: python, string, nlp

I have following simple text:

```
2 of 5 deliveries some text some text... 1. 3 of 5 items some text some text... 2. 1 of 5 items found in box some text...
```

Now I want that on the basis of numbers [0.-9.] the text should be splitted as following: (each row represents on entry in a list).

```
2 of 5 deliveries some text some text...,
3 of 5 items some text some text...,
1 of 5 items found in box some text...
```

This is the desired output. However, it does not really work with `regex` with `re.split('([0\.-9\.]+)', text)`. It always separates by numbers only. What would be the most clever way to convert this with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
>>> re.split(r'\s+\d+\.\s+', text)
['2 of 5 deliveries some text some text...',
 '3 of 5 items some text some text...',
 '1 of 5 items found in box some text...']
```

EXPLANATION:

```
>>> re.split(r'''
        \s+        # Matches leading spaces to the separator
        \d+        # Matches digit character
        \.         # Matches '.' character
        \s+        # Matches trailing spaces after the separator
        ''', text, flags=re.VERBOSE)

['2 of 5 deliveries some text some text...',
 '3 of 5 items some text some text...',
 '1 of 5 items found in box some text...']
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import re

text = '2 of 5 deliveries some text some text... 1. 3 of 5 items some text some text... 2. 1 of 5 items found in box some text...'

print(re.split('[0-9]\.', text))
```

Output:

```
['2 of 5 deliveries some text some text... ', ' 3 of 5 items some text some text... ', ' 1 of 5 items found in box some text...']
```